# How to get rid of vertical spaces before and after a floating tcolorbox?

Tags: floats, tcolorbox, vertical-spacing

As shown by the following MCE, some vertical spaces are added before and after a `tcolorbox` as soon as it is a `float`ing one. How to get rid of them and obtain the same vertical spaces as the non `float`ing ones?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris.

\begin{tcolorbox}
  Non floating
\end{tcolorbox}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris.

\begin{tcolorbox}[float]
  Floating
\end{tcolorbox}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's the separation common to all in-text floats, which is controlled by `\intextsep`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a couple of ways to control the space above. The space below only adding a `\vspace`. Perhaps a better solution will come up.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
    vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
    mauris.
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        Non floating
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
    vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
    mauris.
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[float, every float=\vspace*{-1ex}]%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        Floating I
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \vspace{-1.5ex} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
    vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
    mauris.
    
    \setlength{\intextsep}{2ex plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt} %<<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{tcolorbox}[float]
        Floating II
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \vspace{-1ex} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
    vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
    mauris.

\end{document}
```